# How to multiply using gates?

Tags: digital-logic, adder, multiplier

I need to multiply 2 3bit numbers. I tried that:

[image]

but it does not seem to work.

In this example, the output should be 49. so that is that 77?

Comment: Are the blocks labelled "FA" meant to be full adders?

Comment: Look at the Wiki article referred to by @clabacchio. Specifically, the binary multiplication section.  You'll see that your project is 2 shifts, 2 adds, and a handful of AND gates.

Comment: you just made a concatenator- 7 and 7 give 77

Answer (score 3):

I'm having a hard time trying to understand the schematic...however: there are several different architectures for binary multipliers, but all of them are based on simple considerations.

1- The multiplication in binary logic is made by the AND operator. Therefore you will need a battery of AND gates that multiply each bit of one factor for each bit of the other.

To make it simpler, let's call the factors A and B, of M and N bits respectively. The AND product of the two numbers will give N vectors of M bits, with increasing weight. Now you have to sum up all the vectors considering the weight of each one, to obtain the result.

Long story short: I see the full adders, but you first miss the AND operators.

Some more info on [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_multiplier).

Comment: Thanks. but I didn't understand .. where to use the AND gates?

Comment: @user1798362 did you try to google it?

Comment: Of course. I ask here just after a lot of search on Google without answer.

Comment: @user1798362 I find it strange, because I found it in the first results :) http://www.asic-world.com/images/digital/binary_multiplier.gif

Comment: Oh , Well , I didn't think about search images. thanks. I'll try it.